# Filter a form within another form for data submission

Tags: php, laravel, forms, select, roles

I'm working in Laravel 7.4. I have roles that correspond to two different "projects" or "areas", but they are all in the same table called "roles" and we can differentiate them with the "display_name" field, but I want my form to create a new User to show me the roles according to the "area" selected.

I've tried adding a condition in my controller and another form with the select, but since it's inside the form that submits the data to create the user, it's giving me trouble (the problem is that the data is sent as if the select were a submit button so it gives me the error that I have to fill in the name and email fields but I don't want that to happen).
What can I do?

- This is my view

```xml
<form method="POST" action="{{route('User.store')}}">
  {{ csrf_field() }}
  @include('user.form', ['user'=> new App\User])
  <!--Roles-->
  <br>
  <div class="row justify-content-center text-center">
    <h3 class="txt-unam text-center text-primary">Roles</h3>
  </div>
    
  <div class="my-custom-scrollbar col-md-6">
    <table class="table-scroll table table-sm table-striped ">
      <thead class="txt-grey text-center">
        <tr>
          <th class="th-sticky bg-darker text-center">Role</th>
          <th class="th-sticky bg-darker text-center">Select</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        <form class="row justify-content-center " action="{{url('User')}}">
          <select onchange="this.form.submit()" class="col-sm-6 col-12 form-control" name="id" id="selectRole">
            <option selected value="" name="servescol">Servescol Roles</option>
            <option selected value="" name="indicators">Indicators Roles</option>
          </select>
        </form>
        @foreach($roles as $role)
          <tr>
            <td class="align-middle small text-center">{{$role->display_name}}</td>
            <td class="align-middle text-center"><input type="checkbox" value="{{$role->id}}" id="checkIrRol" name="roles[]" {{$role->pluck('id')->contains($role->id) ? 'checked' : ''}}</td>
          </tr>
        @endforeach
      </tbody>
    </table>
  </div>
  <br>
  <div class="text-center">
    <div class="text-center pt-0">
      <button class="btn btn-success" type="submit" value="Save">Save</button>
      <button class="btn btn-danger" onclick="cancel()" value="Cancel">Cancel</button>
    </div>
  </div>
</form>
```

- This is my Controller

```php
public function create(Request $request)
{
    if ($request->get('servescol')) {
        $roles = DB::select('SELECT id, role_name FROM roles WHERE id <= 6');
        return view('user.create', compact('roles'));
    }
            
    if ($request->get('indicators')) {
        $roles = DB::select('SELECT id, role_name FROM roles WHERE id > 6');

        return view('user.create', compact('roles'));
    }
    
    $roles = Role::orderby('id')->get();
    $departments = Department::all(['id', 'department_name']);
    
    return view('user.create', compact('roles', 'departments'));
}
```

By the way, Departments is something different than "areas". The conditions `<= 6` and `> 6` correspond to the id according to the areas they belong to.

Comment: I don't think it's valid html to put a form inside a tbody like that. It should be `<tbody><tr><td colspan=2> <form>...</form> </td></tr> .... </tbody>`

Comment: You can't have nested forms

Comment: You could use the  query string instead of a form inside a form.

Answer (score 0):

Using the query string, You could make something like

```xml
<tbody>
  <tr>
    <td colspan="2">
      <select onchange="location.search = '?type=' + this.value">
        <option selected disabled></option>
        <option value="servescol">Servescol Roles</option>
        <option value="indicators">Indicators Roles</option>
      </select>      
    </td>
  </tr>
</tbody>
```

```
if ($request->query('type') === 'servescol') {
    $roles = DB::select('SELECT id, role_name FROM roles WHERE id <= 6');

    return view('user.create', compact('roles'));
}
        
if ($request->query('type') === 'indicators') {
    $roles = DB::select('SELECT id, role_name FROM roles WHERE id > 6');

    return view('user.create', compact('roles'));
}
```